# H12 Request Timeout error while deploying ML model with flask in Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, scikit-learn

I am trying to deploy one ML model using flask in Heroku. Here are the files I have:
model.py, app.py, requirement.txt, procfile
Github link-: https://github.com/dee-walia20/clickbait_detector

Model.py code snippet

```
# Importing the libraries

import pandas as pd
import pickle
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import nltk
import re
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet, stopwords
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

#Import dataset and assign Input & Output
data = pd.read_csv('clickbait_data.csv')
X=data.headline
y=data.clickbait

#Custom Transformer built from sklearn for Text Processing
class TextPreprocessor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, lemmatizer=None, stopwords=None,token=True):
        self.token = token
        self.lemmatizer=lemmatizer
        self.stopwords=stopwords

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        if self.token:
            nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
            nltk.download('wordnet')
            X=X.apply(lambda x: re.sub('\d+',"",x))
            X=X.apply(lambda x: re.sub('\W'," ",x))
            X=X.apply(lambda x: re.sub("  "," ",x))
            X=X.apply(lambda x: x.lower())
            self.lemmatizer=WordNetLemmatizer()
            nltk.download("stopwords")
            self.stopwords=stopwords.words('english')
            X=X.apply(lambda x: " ".join([self.lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, self._get_wordnet_pos(word)) 
                          for word in x.split() if word not in self.stopwords]))
        return X
    def _get_wordnet_pos(self, word):
        tag=nltk.pos_tag([word])[0][1][0].upper()
        tag_dict={'J':wordnet.ADJ,
                  'N':wordnet.NOUN,
                  'V':wordnet.VERB,
                  'R':wordnet.ADV
                 }
        return tag_dict.get(tag,wordnet.NOUN)

#Splitting Training and Test Set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.20, random_state=10)

#Creating the pipeline for End to end ML model

tp=TextPreprocessor()
tf=TfidfVectorizer()
model=MultinomialNB()
pipeline=make_pipeline(tp,tf,model)

#Fitting model with trainig data
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Saving model to disk
pickle.dump(pipeline, open('pipeline.pkl','wb'), protocol=-1)

# Loading model to check performance on Test set

if __name__ == "__main__":
    saved_pipeline = pickle.load(open('pipeline.pkl','rb'))
    print("Classitication Report\n",classification_report(y_test, saved_pipeline.predict(X_test)))
```

app.py

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pickle
from model import TextPreprocessor

app = Flask(__name__)

model = pickle.load(open('pipeline.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    '''
    For rendering results on HTML GUI
    '''

    final_features = pd.Series(data=str(request.form['headline']))
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)


    output = prediction[0]

    return render_template('result.html', prediction=output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Error message:

> 2020-05-02T11:25:36.304845+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12
>   desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=clickbait-headline-detector.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=3aa2f839-109a-4c41-a121-3738e440a62f fwd="180.151.118.230"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
>   protocol=https

I have read about 30ms timeout in Heroku for H12 error and possible solution to create background/worker taks. But I am not aware which task would be worker here and how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO; pleae do not clutter your post with unnecessary stuff like "==="

Comment: Thanks it was my first question in stackflow. will keep in mind.

Comment: Celery is what you need here, You have to use it for predict endpoint.

Comment: thanks @1UC1F3R616 for mentioning celery. So i should create a task.py and use it for  `prediction = model.predict(final_features)` part right?